# Numbering Array Elements - Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have an array named c.
Its elements are filenames found in the current directory. How do I list them on their own line with a number before?
For example:

```
1. aaa
2. filename2
3. bbb
4. asdf
```

The code I have now just prints each file on its own line. Like:

```
aaa
filename2
bbb
asdf
```

My code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
c=( $(ls --group-directories-first $*) )

   printf '%s\n' "${c[@]}"
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything for this?

Comment: You asked about numbering arrays, not creating them, but the creation part deserves comment:  `c=( $(ls --group-directories-first $*) )` will lead to problems if any of your files have whitespace in their names.

Comment: I see that now @John1024, thanks for mentioning that. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: The simplest is `c=( * )`.  This will create an array with all file names and is safe to use whatever characters are in the file names.  This does approach, however, does not offer the `--group-directories-first` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with array `c`, here are three methods:

#### Using `cat -n`

The `cat` utility will number output lines:

```
$ cat -n < <(printf "%s\n" "${c[@]}")
     1  aaa
     2  filename2
     3  bbb
     4  asdf
```

#### Using `bash`

This method uses shell arithmetic to number the lines:

```
$ count=0; for f in "${c[@]}"; do  echo "$((++count)). $f"; done
1. aaa
2. filename2
3. bbb
4. asdf
```

#### Using `nl`

In the comments, twalberg suggests the use of `nl`:

```
$ nl < <(printf "%s\n" "${c[@]}")
     1  aaa
     2  filename2
     3  bbb
     4  asdf
```

The utility `nl` has a number of options for controlling exactly how you want the numbering done including, for example, left/right justification, inclusion of leading zeros.  See `man nl`.

Comment: `nl` is a useful alternative to `cat -n` that has a number of options for controlling exactly how you want the numbering done...

Comment: Thanks John1024, I used bash (the second method) to fix it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @twalberg, Excellent suggestion.  I added `nl` to the answer.  JRM1201, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#c[@]}; i++)); do
printf '%d. %s\n' $((i+1)) "${c[$i]}"
done
```